# Is this the expected SSE EventSource reconnect behavior?

Tags: javascript, html, server-sent-events

TLDR: Is EventSource supposed to reconnect constantly even when it's already connected?

I've got a simple SSE implementation working, and I'm curious about whether the behavior I'm seeing is expected. Here's the JS:

```
source = new EventSource("http://localhost:8000/stream")

source.onopen = function(e) {
  console.log(e);
}
source.onmessage = function(e) {
  console.log(e);
}
```

Here's the behavior I'm seeing: The client successfully connects, and after the amount of time defined in the event stream's `reconnection time` it reconnects. This is the behavior even if the client is still connected and receiving events from the server.

I was expecting that the reconnection logic would only trigger after a disconnect or error, but it appears to just reconnect constantly. Neither the server nor client appear to have closed the connection prematurely, and perhaps this is working as intended.

Thoughts?

Comment: that isn't supposed to be. that sounds like a bad server implementation rather than the client. that doesn't sound quite right.

Comment: Yeah, it's not what I was expecting either. I'll go back to mucking with the server. Events do appear to be successfully sending, and there is no close event received on the client, which is weird.

The log looks like:

`open
message
message
message
message
...
open
message
message
...`

Comment: There's a onerror event too

Comment: @DanielA.White -- Yeah, I have that implemented too. No errors being caught by the client.

Answer (score 1):

Have confirmed that this is not the intended behavior. [This sample SSE implementation](https://gist.github.com/ismasan/3fb75381cd2deb6bfa9c) from [Ismasan](https://gist.github.com/ismasan) appropriately keeps the connection alive.